# Series Design in Influxdb for showing number of repeat customers

Tags: statistics, analytics, influxdb

Consider an analytics where you need to find out repeat customers for a date range. Repeat customers are defined for date range as customers who use the service 3*(Given Date Range Interval) before the starting range and also used the service in given date range.

`For example repeat customer for this week is all customers who used service 3 weeks before starting of this week and all such customers used it this week.`

I am using `influxdb`. I haven't decided the series yet, I am looking for inputs into how I can define a series such that I can do available operations in `influxdb` to obtain this analytics.

Data available to me is the timestamp at which user used the facility, user_id , service_category, service_instance_id, and a json dump of further details about service.

may be my thought process is limited, I need some intervention on how to approach this and any input is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

So I thought about this and came to a decent solution. I have to save the last time a user visited along with the entry. So at least one reference will be there for any time period if user is repeating for that time period.

This is similar to a linkedlist except that we have direct access to time based filtering of nodes.